# 2FSK implementation with VCO GNURadio

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, modulation, gnuradio, fsk

I am fairly new to GNURadio. I am trying to generate a 2FSK with minimum frequency shift. Instead of multiplying with a 8MHz complex carrier, I directly use VCO to generate two frequencies. One at 7.5MHz and the other at 8.5MHz. At the output, QT Gui Frequency Sink shows these two frequencies. I have attached my flow graph. Since I need a continuous phase, I use the VCO.

I have two questions.

1. When I use 25M sampling rate, I get different amplitudes in the signal. I only want the frequency difference but amplitudes are also changed. For 18M sampling rate, I do not see two frequencies with complex output, hence I use a higher sampling rate. The amplitude change does not exists for small sampling rates (like 48k) and vco sensitivities. I use the parameters according to https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/VCO Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
2. VCO complex has an imaginary component where as VCO (float) does not. When I take the VCO float output, is it equivalent to the 'real' part of modulated transmitting signal? (Is it equivalent to generating IQ signals and multiplying with a complex carrier and filtering the real component?)  [image: gnuradio flow chart]

Comment: Your sensitivity makes no sense. Your highest frequency that the VCO produces needs to be less than half the sampling rate (or it will get aliased). So, fix your sensitivity first. Then: Your amplitude observation only applies to the real valued VCO, right (not to the magnitude of the complex values coming out of the complex VCO)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The highest frequency VCO produces is 9MHz. The value for sensitivity is put as 2*pi*freq which is 56.52M. So my sampling rate which is 25M is more than twice (18M) what VCO can produce.  The Multiply Const and Add Const block then can generate 7500MHz and 8500MHz. I did the calculation as mentioned https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/VCO. Is that incorrect?

Comment: For the second part of your comment: I can see the amplitude fluctuations both in complex VCO output and real valued VCO output.